# jQuery with Callback and Complete

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I want to use a callback function within `.fadeOut()` after it complete's the animation.  I can do this successfully using the following, no problem. Works just like I want (The HTML and CSS are just a single black square div)

```
function fadeOutThing(speed, callback) {
  $('div').parent().fadeOut(speed, function() {
      if (typeof callback === "function") {
        callback();
      }
  });
}  

function OtherThing() {
    console.log("hello");
}

fadeOutThing(5000, OtherThing);
```

What I really want is for that callback function have its own argument, which could be another callback function, like the following.  The problem is that when I do this, the log will display before the animation is complete: [Here's the fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kevmon/3s85m0en/3/)

```
function fadeOutThing(speed, callback) {
  $('div').parent().fadeOut(speed, function() {
      if (typeof callback === "function") {
        callback();
      }
  });
}  

function OtherThing(stuff) {
    console.log("hello" + stuff); //This displays too soon!
}

fadeOutThing(5000, OtherThing(' stuffsss'));
```

Why is this happening?  What am I not understanding?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is because you call `OtherThing()` immediately on load of the page. This means you're giving the *result* of the `OtherThing()` function as the callback parameter, not the *reference* to the function.

To do what you require you can provide an anonymous function to the callback which wraps your `OtherThing()` call:

```
fadeOutThing(5000, function() {
    OtherThing(' stuffsss'));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Bind the argument instead of calling the function as follows:

```
fadeOutThing(5000, OtherThing.bind(this,' stuffsss'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Your are using/calling function in attribute so instead of function declaration you send its return in this case is no return so:

```
fadeOutThing(5000, OtherThing(' stuffsss'));
```

equals

```
fadeOutThing(5000, notDeclaredNothing); //undefined variable
```

To send function declaration and set paramaters you could do for example third paramater:

```
function fadeOutThing(speed, callback,attrs) {
  $('div').parent().fadeOut(speed, function() {
      if (typeof callback === "function") {
        callback(attrs); //use with attributes
      }
  });
}
```

usage:

```
fadeOutThing(5000, OtherThing,'stuffsss');
```

Or second option is to use bind - bind creates new function with given this and given attributes:

```
fadeOutThing(5000, OtherThing.bind(this,'stuffsss'));
```

This in global scope is window object.